# Is it true that $\sum_{|k|\le n}|x_{k,n}||y_k|\to0$ if $|x_{k,n}|\to0$ for each $k$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|y_k|<\infty$. Is it true that
> $$
> a_n=\sum_{k=-n}^n\Bigl|f\Bigl(\frac k{B_n}\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac{|k|}n\Bigr)-1\Bigr||y_k|\to0
> $$
> as $n\to\infty$, where $\lim_{u\to0}f(u)=1$ and $B_n\to\infty$ but $nB_n^{-1}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$? What if we additionally assume that $f$ is bounded?

For each fixed $k\in\mathbb Z$, $f(k/B_n)\to1$ and $(1-|k|/n)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, for each fixed $k\in\mathbb Z$, $|f(k/B_n)(1-|k|/n)-1|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. So it might seem plausible that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ but I suspect that the convergence might depend on how quickly $f(u)\to1$ as $u\to0$ and I am wondering if the boundedness of $f$ would help.

This problem arises when we try to show that the lag-window estimator of the spectral density function is asymptotically unbiased.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If f is bounded, this should follow from dominated converge.